# The best way to save data from std::istream to file

Tags: c++, windows, file, stream

I have some data in `std::istream` and I need to save it to the disk. Here is my draft:

```
    std::istream& i_stream = ReceiveBytes();

    FILE* pFile;
    pFile = fopen("C:\\my_file.exe", "wb");
    char buffer[1024] = {0x0};
    i_stream.read(buffer, 1024);
    std::streamsize n = i_stream.gcount();

    while (n > 0)
    {  
        if (i_stream)
        {
            fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), pFile);
            i_stream.read(buffer, 1024);
            n = i_stream.gcount();
        }
        else n = 0;
    }

    fclose(pFile);
```

For some reason I don't save all the data from `i_stream`, I lose about 50 bytes in the end of the `i_stream`. What did I do wrong in the code? Is there any better solutions to save data from `std::istream` to a file ?

Comment: Probably `if (i_stream)` fails after the final call to `i_stream.read()` so the final `fwrite` doesn't get called.

Comment: Also, in `fwrite` you should be writing `n` bytes, not `sizeof(buffer)` bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CRLF ("\r\n") input sequences, might be converted to simple LF ("\n").
There's a bug in the fwrite, the code attempts to write 1024 bytes, no matter what.
There's no error checking on the output open, write or close.

More idiomatic is to have the input tests once in the while condition :

```
std::streamsize n;
i_stream.read(buffer, 1024);
while (i_stream || (n = istream.gcount()) != 0) {
    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), n, pFile);
    if (n) { i_stream.read(buffer, 1024) };
}
```

By mixing C++ streams and C stdio functions, the code's less consistent, than if it used streams for both read and write.  An example of code to copy a binary file, using ifstream & ofstream is given at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/ which might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible issues.  The first is that the
`std::istream` you're using may not have been opened in binary
mode; you don't show us this.  The second is that you're using
unformatted input.  If you don't read the full `1024` bytes,
then the `failbit` will be set in `i_stream`.  The test for
having read anything (even less than enough) bytes with
a formatted read is `i_stream || istream.gcount() != 0` (or for
failure, `!istream && istream.gcount() == 0`).