# Read files from URL in C++ instead of local files using Point Cloud Library

Tags: c++, pointers, networking, point-cloud-library

I'm new to Point Cloud library (PCL) and have limited C++ knowledge about how pointers work. While we can load a file from a file and visualize it (using **[this](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/cloud_viewer.php#cloud-viewer)** tutorial), how can we read it from a HTTP URL?

```
int main () {
        pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>);
        pcl::io::loadPCDFile ("my_point_cloud.pcd", *cloud);

    pcl::visualization::CloudViewer viewer("Cloud Viewer");

    //blocks until the cloud is actually rendered
    viewer.showCloud(cloud);

    //use the following functions to get access to the underlying more advanced/powerful
    //PCLVisualizer

    while (!viewer.wasStopped ())
    {
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++ has no native facilities to open a file directly from a HTTP URL. You need to use a third-party library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know whether PCL does this directly, but you can use the [cpr](https://github.com/whoshuu/cpr/) or [urdl](http://think-async.com/Urdl/doc/html/index.html) C++ libraries either to [download the file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4652417/1593077) to a local temporary one, or actually work on a stream.

Urdl example:

```
// For urdl::url.
#include <urdl/url.hpp>

// etc...    

urdl::url url("http://somehost/path");
urdl::istream is("http://somehost/path");
```

and this istream can be used either directly (if PCL supports that), or you can [write the data on the stream to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23832795/1593077).

Example program using cpr (a.k.a. C++ Requests; based on the C library `libcurl`):

```
#include <cpr/cpr.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    auto r = cpr::Get(cpr::Url{"https://api.github.com/repos/whoshuu/cpr/contributors"},
                      cpr::Authentication{"user", "pass"},
                      cpr::Parameters{{"anon", "true"}, {"key", "value"}});
    r.status_code;                  // 200
    r.header["content-type"];       // application/json; charset=utf-8
    r.text;                         // JSON text string
}
```

(taken from cpr's official website.)

Comment: Thanks. This is good. But what I need to do is probably copy it to memory and once done, visualize it. CURL looks nice, but how to interface the `istream` to the `*cloud`?

Comment: @Ariana: Updated my answer with something nicer, wrapping libcurl. To answer your question: Hopefully PCL can take its input from an istream; otherwise, perhaps from a C-string (and then you can probably use something like `r.text.begin()` in the cpr example). If not, save the data to a file and use the same load function you had in your example.